# what is してき in this sentence?

Tags: conditionals, ellipsis

I tried looking up a similar example to this sentence, but I couldn't:

> 図鑑読んで出直してきな

this isn't the whole sentence, the first part ends with たら conditional.

Comment: "this isn't the whole sentence" - Always give the whole sentence and more whenever possible. Wasn't a big deal here, but many times context is everything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are parsing it incorrectly.

「出直{でなお}して・き・な」 = 「出直す」+「くる」+「な」

「な」 here is a sentence-ending particle that functions as an ***informal imperative-softener***.

Thus, 「きな」 means virtually the same thing as 「来{き}なさい」

> "Come again after reading the picture book, will you?"