# What verb form is してきた?

Tags: grammar, subsidiary-verbs

What is してきた?

> 文化という言葉は、芸術や学問など人間が生み出した高い達成度を持つもの（ハイカルチャー）を指すとともに、人間の社会が長年にわたって形成**してきた**慣習や振舞いの体系を指す ([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E6%96%87%E5%8C%96))

I suppose it's a conjugated form of する, but I [can't find it](http://www.japaneseverbconjugator.com/Suru.asp).

I don't know if it has anything to do with this [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61007/what-is-%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8D-in-this-sentence).

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/677/30454  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18965/30454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

して is the te-form of する, and きた is the past form of くる. Here, くる is one of the Japanese [subsidiary verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010) that adds a feeling of "over a period of time (up until now)". See:

- [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)
- [What's the difference between 歩んでいった and 歩んできた?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25505/5010)

Technically speaking, subsidiary verbs like (-て)いく, (-て)しまう and (-て)みる are not part of verb conjugations. They are different verbs, as the name suggests. The conjugation list you linked does not show every possible combination of a verb and a subsidiary verb because they are not conjugations in the first place. (As an exception, the so-called "-teiru form" is on the list even though いる is a subsidiary verb. This is only for the convenience of beginners whose first language is English.)